# Casting a `local int*` to `local long16*` causes the kernel give me wrong results

Tags: opencl

I have a `__local int*` pointer which I want to copy the data from a `__global int*` to it. To make the copy faster, I cast both to `long16*`, I know all the arrays (input, output and local memory) are of size `16 * 1024 bytes`. The code is as follows:

```
__kernel void test_kernel(
  __global int* a,
  __global int* b,
  __local int* localbuf
  ){

   int thread_idx = get_global_id(0);
   int local_idx  = get_local_id(0);

   __global long16* input     = (__global long16*)a;
   __global long16* output    = (__global long16*)b;
   __local  long16* local_buf = (__local long16*)localbuf;

   local_buf[local_idx * 4 + 0] = input[0];
   local_buf[local_idx * 4 + 1] = input[1];
   local_buf[local_idx * 4 + 2] = input[2];
   local_buf[local_idx * 4 + 3] = input[3];

   barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE); 

   output[thread_idx] = local_buf[thread_idx];
}
```

The result is not as I expect and `output` is filled with zeros.

Now, if I simplly replace the `local_buf` in last line with `input`, still I will get all zeros in `output`:

```
__kernel void test_kernel(
  __global int* a,
  __global int* b,
  __local int* localbuf
  ){

   int thread_idx = get_global_id(0);
   int local_idx  = get_local_id(0);

   __global long16* input     = (__global long16*)a;
   __global long16* output    = (__global long16*)b;
   __local  long16* local_buf = (__local long16*)localbuf;

   local_buf[local_idx * 4 + 0] = input[0];
   local_buf[local_idx * 4 + 1] = input[1];
   local_buf[local_idx * 4 + 2] = input[2];
   local_buf[local_idx * 4 + 3] = input[3];

   barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE); 

   output[thread_idx] = input[thread_idx];
}
```

But if I remove the assignment lines to the local buffer as follows:

```
__kernel void test_kernel(
  __global int* a,
  __global int* b,
  __local int* localbuf
  ){

   int thread_idx = get_global_id(0);
   int local_idx  = get_local_id(0);

   __global long16* input     = (__global long16*)a;
   __global long16* output    = (__global long16*)b;
   __local  long16* local_buf = (__local long16*)localbuf;

   barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE); 

   output[thread_idx] = input[thread_idx];
}
```

I will get the values totally correct in the `output` array. Also, if I simply do not cast the `localbuf` to `long16` and copy it as `int`s, everything will work fine.

I really do not know what can be the problem. I am using a `nVIDIA GTX 560 Ti`.

***Update 1:*** I noticed that this problem does not exist on AMD R9 280X and nVIDIA GTX 280... So, it can be architecture dependent.

***Update2: Source Code:***

```
  size_t buffer_size = 16 * 1024 / 4 ;
  size_t global_ws = buffer_size;
  size_t local_ws = 32;

  std::vector<int> host_data (buffer_size);
  std::vector<int> output_data(buffer_size);
  for(size_t i = 0; i < buffer_size; i++){
    host_data[i] = static_cast<int>(i);
    output_data[i] = 0;
  }

  cl_mem input  = clCreateBuffer(cl->devices[0].ctx, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, buffer_size * sizeof(int), host_data.data(), &err);     CL_ERROR(err);
  cl_mem output = clCreateBuffer(cl->devices[0].ctx, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY, buffer_size * sizeof(int), nullptr, &err);     CL_ERROR(err);

    auto start_frame_time = hrc::now();

    clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), &input);
    clSetKernelArg(kernel, 1, sizeof(cl_mem), &output);
    clSetKernelArg(kernel, 2, buffer_size*sizeof(cl_int), NULL);

    err = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(cl->devices[0].cmd_queue, kernel, 1, nullptr, &global_ws, &local_ws, 0, nullptr, nullptr); CL_ERROR(err);

    clFinish(cl->devices[0].cmd_queue);

    err = clEnqueueReadBuffer(cl->devices[0].cmd_queue, output, CL_TRUE, 0, buffer_size * sizeof(int), output_data.data(), 0, nullptr, nullptr); CL_ERROR(err);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < buffer_size; i++){
      std::cout << i << ". " << output_data[i] << std::endl;
      if (i % 512 == 0) getchar();
    }

    std::cout << "Elapsed Time: " << hrc::now() - start_frame_time << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
long -> 8 bytes
int -> 4 bytes
long16 -> 128 bytes
```

`long16` is 32 times bigger than `int`.

So if you have 16kB of input/local/output you can only have (according to your kernel code) 512 work items. How many are you launching? Can you put that code as well?

For nVIDIA platform, if you go over these limits, you will get an error not at the kernel launch time but at the `enqueueRead()`. And the output will not even be read (leaving the output array with zeros). Check the errors there.

Also, AMD/Others might look like it works, but then have half of the results will be wrong.

Comment: Actually you are right! I am getting `CL_OUT_OF_RESOURCES` on `clEnqueueRead` but I don't know why the same code is running on AMD without any problems. Also, the results are complete.
Also, I put the code in the question as an update.

Comment: You were right! I was going out of the arrays scope. I will add the answer to question soon.